# SwiftUI Firebase - How to query a document then update?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

Trying to query a document and then update it in a function in my ViewModel. Trying something like the below, but it doesn't work. Any advice would be appreciated!

```
func addToFruits(name: String) {
    db.collection("fruits").whereField("name", isEqualTo: name)
        .getDocument()
        .limit(to: 1)
        .updateData(["fruits": FieldValue.arrayUnion([name])])
}


func addToRoutine(routine: String, habit: String) {
    db.collection("routines").whereField("name", isEqualTo: routine).getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                document.updateData(["habits": FieldValue.arrayUnion([habit])])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the first one, error I get is "Value of type 'Query' has no member 'getDocument'" and not sure how to resolve this. Second one, error I get is "Value of type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot' has no member 'updateData'"

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do there - if you're performing a query you should be expecting one or more results so using `.getDocuments` is what you want. See [Execute a Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query).

Comment: Note that the code is also malformed - missing the closure code etc so it won't work as is. You'll need to move the `.updateData` code to inside the closure following the `.getDocuments` function (once that's corrected)

Comment: Can you provide an example here? I've tried many different things but still cant get this to work. I've updated the above with another example I tried. Trying to just find one document and add to that one document

Comment: It would really benefit you to go through the Getting Started guide, [Writing Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data) as what your asking is covered. Take a look at that link, see that a document doesn't have an updateData function, a [documentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/DocumentReference#updatedata_:) does. So once you know the documentID or have the document, you can create a reference to it and then update. Reiterating that doing that in a loop will update *all* of the results.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly clear what you're attempting to update but here's some quick example code that will read in a user named 'Steve' and update his age to 50. Keep in mind this will read in the FIRST user named 'Steve' and update their age - then when it's run again, will read the NEXT Steve etc etc - that may be what your attempting to do.

```
func readUsersAndUpdateTheirAgeTo50() {
    let users = self.db.collection("users") //self.db points to *my* firestore
    users.whereField("name", isEqualTo: "Steve").limit(to: 1).getDocuments(completion: { querySnapshot, error in
        if let err = error {
            print(err.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        guard let docs = querySnapshot?.documents else { return }

        for doc in docs {
            let docId = doc.documentID
            let name = doc.get("name")
            print(docId, name)

            let ref = doc.reference
            ref.updateData(["age": 20])
        }
    })
}
```

If I just wanted to update all Steve's age to 50, remove the limit

```
.limit(to: 1)
```

Note this code is kind of sloppy as since there is a limit of 1, we wouldn't need the loop. Also note that not every Steve is 50 so there should be additional parameters to narrow down which Steve it is - like a uid for example.